# How much daily activity does a Newfypoo need?

Tags: dogs, health, training, play, pet-selection

I am thinking about getting a Newfypoo (a cross between a Newfoundland and a Poodle) puppy. How much daily playtime and training does a Newfypoo need on average?

Comment: If you need to ask a question like this, chances are you're ot reay for a puppy. Puppies are strenuous work and require *at least* 2 hours of exercise per day. Use discretion as you look further into this process and make sure to read a few books. One that I highly recommend is the dog whisperer.

Comment: Energy levels vary even inside the same litter of puppies, in some cases even more than between different breeds. Since this is a mixed breed dog (puppy) it is quite impossible to say what kind of dog it'll be when grown up. Chances are, considering the parent breeds, this puppy will be a clever one. Hard to say anything more than that.

Comment: @Jeremy That's not fair. It is a perfectly reasonable question, and one lots of people ask when they start thinking about getting a puppy.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that I'm far from an expert; I just want to share my personal experiences and what I've learned from recently getting my first dog.

In my opinion, the breed of the dog doesn't matter as much as choosing a dog that matches your energy level. *

If you jog for 2 hours every day and want to take your dog with you, you would choose a puppy with slightly higher energy level than, say, someone who lives in an apartment and cannot take his dog out regularly.

Getting a dog with a higher/lower energy level than you may cause problems down the road; you wouldn't want a hyperactive dog due to lack of exercise.

Spend some time with the puppy, take it for a walk (if you can) and, depending on the age, you should get a rough idea of the puppy's energy level. If its possible in your case, spend some time with more than one puppy; it may be easier to compare energy levels, if you have no previous experience like me.

So to answer your question, energy levels vary greatly, even between puppies from the same litter. Try to pick one that matches *your* energy level.

[*] Having said that, some breeds can naturally be more active than others.

Some more info:

[Cesar Millan - Adopt a Dog with the Right Energy](http://www.cesarsway.com/tips/yournewdog/finding-a-dog-with-the-right-energy)

Best of luck.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but I'd like to point out that breeds do matter, as certain breeds are higher energy than others. Working dogs will generally require more exercise than show dogs for example.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I mentioned that some breeds may be more active. Working dogs are a good example.

Comment: Also ask a the breeder. A good breeder will make sure you are the right match for the dog and they will know their dogs and be able to help select the most laid back pup from the litter. If you are new to dogs you will do best with a laid back dog.

Answer (score 3):

I currently have a 1-year old Newfypoo. Honestly, they are more low-key and sweet than most puppies, although they are still a puppies and the poodle breed has undesirable characteristics due to its intelligence. Here was our experience:

At the time we got the puppy, we had semi-opposite work schedules, when we did work some of the same days.  Schedule included 1 hour of playing & training in the morning, until about 8 months.  This does not help you get ready for work, as the puppy required full attention.  A 15-minute walk before we went to work.  Crated the puppy.  As a poodle mix, Newfypoos are known for separation anxiety and will chew/eat things when left alone.  The dog walker would either come over around 1 PM, or we would took him to doggie daycare for the day (maximum twice a week, otherwise too much physical play for a large breed; you have to restrict high-impact exercise).  Another 15-minute walk when we came home, plus one more hour of play & training.

The biggest problem we had was when he misbehaved and had puppy temper fits, they were from a giant breed puppy.  You must train a Newfypoo very strictly due to their size.  There is a helpful growth chart at [Newyfoo Breed](http://www.newfypoobreed.com).